# What is difference between Github Project and Git from Source Code Management?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

[image]

What is difference between Github Project and Git from Source Code Management in Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github is dedicated to using github services and it unlocks specific github features.

The other will work with any git SCM server including external vendors (github, bitbucket, your own infrastructure , team foundations server etc) . This means it will support only git standard features, nothing that is vendor specific.

You can configure both without problem.

If you install bitbucket plugin, you will have a similar third section.